# cypress passing selector to variable for reuse

Tags: javascript, cypress

How to refactor below selector?

```
cy.get('ul.nav').findByText("home").should("exist");
cy.get('ul.nav').findByText("contact").should("exist");
```

I tried

```
const ul = cy.get('ul.nav');
ul.findByText("home").should("exist");
ul.findByText("contact").should("exist"); //failed
```

the second assertion failed.

Comment: What is that `findByText` method? I do not recognise it.

Comment: You can use aliases to accomplish what you want. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Elements